# gridded air pollution data for Japan

Tags: meteorology, air-pollution, database, japan

Do you know of any database where I can get past air pollution (sulfur oxides (SOx) - nitrogen oxides (NOx) - photochemical oxidants (Ox) - particulate matter (PM) - suspended particulate matter (SPM) - fine particulate matter (PM2.5), etc.) as predicted values on a grid map of Japan?
Or do you know of any studies using such data?
I can find some by prefecture and by base station.

Comment: Welcome to EarthScience.Stackexchange. Do you mean forecast data (=short term future predictionts), mid-term or long term (climate model) predictions? What spatial resolution should the gridded data have?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What I want is historical data. I assume that the data is based on observations and reconstructed into a grid map. I do not limit the resolution.

Comment: Maybe there exists a NICAM-based reanalysis that includes chemistry?  Or otherwise a regional Japanese model?  You could try to ask JMA if you don't get a good answer here.